# Update many in Laravel for one-to-many relationship

Tags: laravel

I have a one-to-many relationship in laravel. Author to Books. How would I update all records in specific book and remove those that are not in my array. For example, `$book` is array with author, page, publication and I want to update those records and at the same time detach those that are not there?

I used `$book->update($array)` but that failed. I also used sync and that failed because it can only be used with many-to-many

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing as worded currently.

Do you mean that you want to update properties on a specific Book model instance?

Comment: I want to update records based on the information I am passing in array. Whatever I have in array should get updated, if some values are missing then detach them completely

Comment: Show an example of your data and what you expect to happen

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example of how to update many records in the model using where conditions.

```
Book::where('author', $author_name)
    ->update([
        'price' => 10000, // Add as many as you need
    ]);

Book::where('author',$author)
    ->where('publication', $publication)
    ->update([
        'price' => 10000,
    ]);

// Or More Dynamic 
Book::whereAuhorAndPublication( $author_name, $publication )
    ->update([
        'price' => 10000,
    ]);
```

it would be nice if you share an example of data and request data.